# Proof that a Fibonacci number even if and only if 3 divides the index

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

[image: Click here for the image]

1) Please can you explain how you can see that a weak mathematical induction will not work? I should only take one Fibonacci number $f_{n}$ in stead of three Fibonacci numbers: $f_{3n-2}, f_{3n-1}$ and $f_{3n}.$

2) Why do they use index $3n-2, 3n-1$ and $3n$ in stead of $n-2, n-1, n$? Because you know that here is always a number divisibly by $3$ when you take $3$ consecutive integers.

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Divisibility_of_Fibonacci_Numbers

Answer (score 2):

The simplest proof is to note this:
$$
f_{n+3} = f_{n+2} + f_{n+1} = f_{n+1} + f_{n} + f_{n+1} = 2 f_{n+1} + f_{n}
$$ 
Therefore, $f_{n+3}$ and $f_{n}$ have the same parity.

Since $f_0=0$ is even, then so is $f_{3n}$.

Since $f_1=f_2=1$ are odd, so are $f_{3n+1}$ and $f_{3n+2}$.

Comment: Sorry, I still do not understand my two questions above.